# How do I find the path to the 32bit version of java on 64bit Linux?

Tags: command-line, java, versions

I've installed a 32 bit version of java on my 64bit system to get Juniper VPN to work. What command line command will allow me to find the path to the 32 bit version of java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see all available `java` executables using the `update-alternatives` tool. For example, on my system:

```
$ update-alternatives --list java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-x64/jre/bin/java
```

Alternatively, you could also just search through `/usr/lib` for executable files called `java`:

```
$ find /usr/lib -name java -type f -executable
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-x64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-x64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is a guide to download and install oracle java in linux](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#Java%20for%20Linux%20Platforms)

If you want to find something in the file system use the find command .

```
sudo find / -name java
```